# How do I change the date only in a C# DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I am looking for a elegant solution (if it exists) to achieve what I described in the title.

I saw an elegant solution for "changing the time in a DateTime object" and it is as follows:

```
DateTime s = ...;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
s = s.Date + ts;
```

If there such a solution for changing the date in a DateTime object?

Comment: Are you trying to change the date to a specific/absolute date ("Jan 4th, 2012") or by a relative amount ("+10 days")? Elegance depends on the full context

Comment: I am trying to change the date to an specific/absolute date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` struct is designed to be immutable, so you can't change it. You can get a new one based on values from the old one, which is exactly what your solution does.

You can make it a bit more clear by using `DateTime` constructor which takes all date and time values: year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds.

```
s = new DateTime(s.Year, s.Month, s.Day, 10, 30, 0);
s = new DateTime(2014, 10, 2, s.Hour, s.Minute, s.Second);
```

or you can use `TimeOfDay` property:

```
s = new DateTime(2014, 10, 2) + s.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are going to pass a new DateTime object to update your existing object, a function like this can work.

```
DateTime UpdateDate(DateTime existingDate, DateTime newDate)
{
    return  newDate.Date + existingDate.TimeOfDay;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution as it also preserves the format of the datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDatetime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Decent one. Short Simple and Sweet

Comment: I believe you are only supposed to change the date portion while preserving the time.  You are discarding the time @AgoraStudent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime constructors, so you can preserve the original time.

See this example:

```
var firstDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 15, 0, 0);
var newDate = DateTime.Now;

// New date, original time.            
firstDate = new DateTime(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day, firstDate.Hour, firstDate.Minute, firstDate.Second, firstDate.Millisecond);
```

Comment: This only preserves the original time down to the millisecond.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dateOnly = now.Date;
 TimeSpan time = now.TimeOfDay;
 dateOnly = DateTime.Parse("5/15/15"); // or whatever date you choose
 DateTime newDateTime = dateOnly + time;
```

Comment: So would this not modify the date? Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote it @thewisegod, but it doesn't preserve the original time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DateTime s = ...;
s = new DateTime(year, month, day) + s.TimeOfDay;
```

That preserves the time in the original DateTime.

Comment: This solution does exactly what @phoenixson asks.  Why the downvote?